# How do I balance the text with the flowchart

Tags: tikz-pgf, formatting, flow-charts

So I have this normal text that is bordering 2 elements: section and the flowchart. The text unfortunately is close to the flowchart but I don't want that. The thing that I want is for the text to be in the middle of the two elements. Here's my existing code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{tgtermes}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

%% array
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

%% enumitem
\setlist[enumerate]{
    labelindent=25pt,
    leftmargin=*,
}
\setlist[itemize]{
    labelindent=25pt,
    leftmargin=*,
}

%% titlesec
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
    {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
    {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter: }
    {0em}
    {\centering} 
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-40pt}{20pt}
\titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}

%% tikz
\tikzset{
  block/.style = {
    rectangle,
    draw,
    text width=5em,
    text centered,
    minimum width=3cm,
    minimum height=1cm,
  },
  line/.style = {
    draw,
    -latex',
  },
  text/.style = {textwidth = 3em}
}

%% personal commands
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\School[1]{\gdef\@School{#1}}
\newcommand*\Department[1]{\gdef\@Department{#1}}
\newcommand*\Author[1]{\gdef\@Author{#1}}
\newcommand\Maketitle{%
  \author{\@Author\\\@School, \@Department}%
  \maketitle
}
\makeatother

%% final settings
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Bài}}
\linespread{1.05}
\raggedbottom

\begin{document}

\label{single}
\let\oldchapter\thechapter
\def\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}\texttt{+}\the\numexpr\value{chapter}+1\relax}
\chapter{Sản xuất giống cây trồng}

\section{Mục đích của công tác sản xuất giống cây trồng}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Duy trì, củng cố độ thuần chủng, sức sống và tính trạng điển hình của giống
    \item Tạo ra số lượng giống cần thết để cung cấp cho sản xuất đại trà
    \item Đưa giống tốt phổ biến vào sản xuất
\end{itemize}
\section{Hệ thống sản xuất giống cây trồng}

Hệ thống sản xuất giống cây trồng gồm 3 giai đoạn

\vspace{3ex}

\medskip

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1cm, auto]
    \node [block] (bl1) {Hạt giống SNC};
    \node [block, below of=bl1, node distance=2cm] (bl2) {Hạt giống \\ NC};
    \node [block, below of=bl2, node distance=2cm] (bl3) {Hạt giống XN};
    \node [below right of = bl3, node distance=3cm] (bl4) {Sản xuất đại trà};

    \path [line] (bl1) -- (bl2);
    \path [line] (bl2) -- (bl3);
    \path [line] (bl3) |- (bl4);

\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ | M{4em} | M{4cm}| M{4cm} |  } 
\hline
 & \textbf{Chất lượng, độ thuần, nguồn gốc} &\textbf{Nơi thực hiện}  \\
 \hline
 \textbf{Hạt siêu nguyên chủng} & Cao \par Được sản xuất từ hạt SNC & Công ty, trung tâm sản xuất giống cây trồng \\
 \hline
 \textbf{Hạt xác nhận} & Cao \par Được sản xuất từ hạt NC & Cơ sở nhân giống, trung tâm và các cơ sở sản xuất để sản xuất đại trà \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\section{Quy trình sản xuất giống cây trồng}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ | M{3em} | M{3cm} | M{3cm} | M{3cm} | M{3cm} | }
        \hline
         & \textbf{Cây tự thụ phấn} &\textbf{Cây thụ phấn chéo} 
         & \textbf{Cây nhân giống vô tính} & \textbf{Cây rừng}  \\
         \hline
         \textbf{Đặc điểm} & Hoa lưỡng tính \ Thời gian chin của nhị và nhụy cùng lúc & Hoa đơn tính hoặc hoa có thời gian chín của nhị và nhụy không cùng lúc & Sinh sản không có sự kết hợp giới đực và cái, con cái giống nhau và giống mẹ & Vòng đời dài \linebreak Từ 5 – 10 năm \\
         \hline
         \textbf{Vật liệu khởi đầu}  & Hạt siêu nguyên chủng & Hạt siêu nguyên chủng & Thế hệ vô tính đạt chuẩn siêu nguyên chủng & Cây trội có đặc tính tốt đã qua khảo nghiệm\\
         \hline
         \textbf{Cách li} & Không yêu cầu cách li cao & Yêu cầu cách li cao & Không cần cách li & Trong điều kiện rừng giống hoặc vườn giống\\
         \hline
         \textbf{Thời gian} & 4 – 5 năm & 4 vụ & & 1 vụ \\
         \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you like?

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{tgtermes}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

%% array
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

%% enumitem
\setlist[enumerate]{
    labelindent=25pt,
    leftmargin=*,
}
\setlist[itemize]{
    labelindent=25pt,
    leftmargin=*,
}

%% titlesec
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
    {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
    {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter: }
    {0em}
    {\centering} 
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-40pt}{20pt}
\titlelabel{\thetitle.\quad}

%% tikz
\tikzset{
  block/.style = {
    rectangle,
    draw,
    text width=5em,
    text centered,
    minimum width=3cm,
    minimum height=1cm,
  },
  line/.style = {
    draw,
    -latex',
  },
  text/.style = {textwidth = 3em}
}

%% personal commands
\makeatletter
\newcommand*\School[1]{\gdef\@School{#1}}
\newcommand*\Department[1]{\gdef\@Department{#1}}
\newcommand*\Author[1]{\gdef\@Author{#1}}
\newcommand\Maketitle{%
  \author{\@Author\\\@School, \@Department}%
  \maketitle
}
\makeatother

%% final settings
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Bài}}
\linespread{1.05}
\raggedbottom

\begin{document}

\label{single}
\let\oldchapter\thechapter
\def\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}\texttt{+}\the\numexpr\value{chapter}+1\relax}
\chapter{Sản xuất giống cây trồng}

\section{Mục đích của công tác sản xuất giống cây trồng}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Duy trì, củng cố độ thuần chủng, sức sống và tính trạng điển hình của giống
    \item Tạo ra số lượng giống cần thết để cung cấp cho sản xuất đại trà
    \item Đưa giống tốt phổ biến vào sản xuất
\end{itemize}
\section{Hệ thống sản xuất giống cây trồng}

Hệ thống sản xuất giống cây trồng gồm 3 giai đoạn
\vspace{4ex}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 1cm, auto]
    \node [block] (bl1) {Hạt giống SNC};
    \node [block, below of=bl1, node distance=2cm] (bl2) {Hạt giống \\ NC};
    \node [block, below of=bl2, node distance=2cm] (bl3) {Hạt giống XN};
    \node [below right of = bl3, node distance=3cm] (bl4) {Sản xuất đại trà};

    \path [line] (bl1) -- (bl2);
    \path [line] (bl2) -- (bl3);
    \path [line] (bl3) |- (bl4);

\end{tikzpicture}
\
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ | M{4em} | M{4cm}| M{4cm} |  } 
\hline
 & \textbf{Chất lượng, độ thuần, nguồn gốc} &\textbf{Nơi thực hiện}  \\
 \hline
 \textbf{Hạt siêu nguyên chủng} & Cao \par Được sản xuất từ hạt SNC & Công ty, trung tâm sản xuất giống cây trồng \\
 \hline
 \textbf{Hạt xác nhận} & Cao \par Được sản xuất từ hạt NC & Cơ sở nhân giống, trung tâm và các cơ sở sản xuất để sản xuất đại trà \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\section{Quy trình sản xuất giống cây trồng}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ | M{3em} | M{3cm} | M{3cm} | M{3cm} | M{3cm} | }
        \hline
         & \textbf{Cây tự thụ phấn} &\textbf{Cây thụ phấn chéo} 
         & \textbf{Cây nhân giống vô tính} & \textbf{Cây rừng}  \\
         \hline
         \textbf{Đặc điểm} & & & & \\
         \hline
         \textbf{Vật liệu khởi đầu} & & & & \\
         \hline
         \textbf{Cách li} & & & & \\
         \hline
         \textbf{Thời gian} & & & & \\
         \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]